# I want htaccess grammar to hide php extension

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder E:\wamp\www\world_appeal
with admin panel E:\wamp\www\world_appeal\admin

I want htaccess grammar that hide php extension for all the files of front and admin panel as well. How?

Comment: Before you say a solution is not working: .htaccess can only change which links work. I doesn't change your document, so you still need to edit the links in your document from `<a href="something.php">` to `<a href="something">`

Answer (score 1):

Place these 2 rules as very first rule in **`/world_appeal/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /world_appeal/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /world_appeal/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/world_appeal/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: after little bit modifying ur code its fine now. in front and admin as well. thank you very much brother. you made my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

put in .htaccess in each folder

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a rewrite for this, you can use the built-in functionality called MultiViews. Simply add just the following line to your `.htaccess`. This will (among other things) negotiate a suitable file extension if you omit it.

```
Options +MultiViews
```